# When i send a email with jinja template the css don't work

Tags: python, css, flask, smtp, jinja2

I´m trying to send a email with jinja template but the styles (css) don´t work

this is the code to i use to send email with the template

```
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = 'Prueba de correo'
    msg['From'] = 'my address email'
    msg['To'] = 'name@domail.com'
    msg.set_content('Correo automatico desde python')

    html = render_template('email.html');
    msg.add_alternative(html,subtype="html")

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465) as server:
        server.login('my address email ','my password')
        server.send_message(msg)
        server.quit()
```

this is the jinja template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='email.css') }}"/> -->
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        h1{
            text-align: center;
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <h1>Hola Mundo</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

but when the email was sended

looks like this

[Email content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc8Lc.png)

and it should be like this

[Template with styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEvhl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried uncommenting out the  tag?

The line should read:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='email.css') }}"/>
```

Comment: yes, first I tried with a external css file but it didn't work so I put the styles in the html